# Serialization in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I am working on an Accounting software package.  Our app allows the user to modify their form design and save it for future use.  For this my client suggested serialization.  The problem is we are using Silverlight 4, which supports `XamlWriter`.  So we decide to store xaml as xml in a database and retrieve it by converting it into uicontrols.  I have used the following code and an error occurs.  The error is:

> Event handler is not supported by XamlReader.

Additionally, it only converts the controls in the first row of the Grid. Other controls are not displayed.

This is the code I'm using:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("/Sampletwo;component/MainPage.xaml");
IEnumerable<XElement> childElements =
from el in doc.Elements()
select el;
foreach (XElement el in childElements)
store = el.LastNode.ToString();
```

Back to UIControls:

```
UIElement tree = (UIElement)XamlReader.Load(store);
grdLayoutRoot.Children.Add(tree);
```

Comment: Are you writing out the XML namespaces as well?

Comment: +1 for providing code with your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to serialize individual parts of a XAML file using XamlReader.Load on individual snippets of XML. That will not work as you are not including the XML namespaces (e.g. from the parent page).

Each piece of Xaml you load needs to be self-contained (as if it were a page itself).

If you also have events defined in controls within the XAML, that would explain the `Event handler is not supported by XamlReader` error message as the loader has no context in which to work out what code-behind belongs to the Xaml (as there is no code-behind using load).